# iOS SideMenu Background Image not displaying correctly

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

I have setup my project to mimic the SideMenu example project to the best of my abilities, but the background image for the sideview is 
not displaying properly. I would like to only have underlines under the cells that I setup, not have a title bar and have the background image stretched across the sidemenu, not repeated several times. I am fairly weak on storyboarding, so if there is any info you need to help with this, please let me know. I have gone through all of the attributes settings I could and can't seem to find anything else helpful.

I have included a picture of the look I want to achieve, my current app and my current tableview in the storyboard interface

Below is my code showing how I am setting up the side menu background image.

```
SideMenuManager.default.menuLeftNavigationController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LeftMenuNavigationController") as? UISideMenuNavigationController
    SideMenuManager.default.menuAnimationBackgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "sidemenubackground")!)
            // Enable gestures. The left and/or right menus must be set up above for these to work.
    // Note that these continue to work on the Navigation Controller independent of the View Controller it displays!
    SideMenuManager.default.menuAddPanGestureToPresent(toView: self.navigationController!.navigationBar)
    SideMenuManager.default.menuAddScreenEdgePanGesturesToPresent(toView: self.navigationController!.view)
```

---

I am trying to achieve this look. My current view repeats the background image repeatedly, has a title bar on the top and has underlines under nonexistent cells:

[image: Screen Shot]

This is what my side menu looks like currently:

[image: Screen Shot]

Here is what my tableview looks like in the storyboard currently:

[image: Screen Shot]

[image: opening gif]

Comment: Have you tried to take the `UIImageView` instead of set `UIColor`? 
If not Just take `UIImageView` and set it to the `viewController` And just set that image on that `ImageView`?

Comment: I have not tried this. The example project supplied with the SideMenu pod is not setup that way, but its a good idea. I will try this next

Comment: Can you please attach the GIF so easy to review.

Comment: Do you mean a gif of the menu opening?

Comment: Yes. Menu opening.

Comment: I added the gif. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure but try this. 

 `SideMenuManager.default.menuAnimationBackgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "sidemenubackground")!)`